# JS jquery and ajax problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i have problem with some things

Here is the code

```
function get_char_val(merk) {
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "char_info2.php",
  data: { name: merk },
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data){return(data);}
});

}
alert(get_char_val("str"));
```

when alert comes out it's output the undefined please help fast i'm making this two days xC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set the async:false config parameter in the ajax call options or use the call back.

Using Async:false -

```
    function get_char_val(merk)
    {  
      var returnValue = null;
        $.ajax
        (
            {   
                type: "POST",
                async:false,   
                url: "char_info2.php",   
                data: { name: merk },   
                dataType: "html",  
                success: function(data){returnValue = data;} 
            }
        ); 
     return returnValue;
    }
    alert(get_char_val("str"));
```

P.S: Note that making ajax calls synchronous is not advisable.

Comment: Agreed...Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: this is considered as pretty bad practice, since each ajax request "blocks" and therefore freezes the browser while running.

Comment: Please check my note in the answer. I guess we pressed submit at the same time :)

Answer (score 3):

`get_char_val` does not return anything.  The `success` callback needs to have `alert(data)` in it to return the data from AJAX.

`$.ajax` is asynchronous - meaning it doesn't happen in order with other code, that is why the callback exists.

Comment: To add to this: You'll get far more data out of console.log(). Install Firebug and use it instead of alert for better debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Your `return;` statement will return the value to the `anonymous function` you pass into the `success handler`. You cannot return a value like this, you need to invoke another callback instead.

```
function get_char_val(merk, cb) {
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "char_info2.php",
      data: { name: merk },
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data){cb.apply(this, data);}
   });
}

get_char_val("str", function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do an asynchronous ajax call, the response of the server is handled in the "success" function. The return in your success function is useless, you should use the "data" parameter directly in the function

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Use it like this.

```
function get_char_val(merk) {
var myReturnData= "";
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "char_info2.php",
  data: { name: merk },
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data){myReturnData = data;}
});
return myReturnData;
}
alert(get_char_val("str"));
```

Just understand the problem with your piece of code. Use the return statement under the right function.